# Can Multidemensional Scaling translate distance of points in a sphere into points on 2-d planer

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I'm wondering that when I used the classical Euclidian distances of points on a 3-d sphere to run cmdscale. Whether I get a list of 2-d points that can represent the details or I get 3-d points.
 And actually, I'm not very clear about the procedure of classical Multidimensional Scaling and how many eigenvectors I should take as the coordinate of the points?